# User authentication with loopback.io and android returns unauthorized exception

Tags: android, node.js, authentication, loopbackjs

I'm trying to log in a user to my loopback.io server following [this](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Android+SDK#AndroidSDK-Usersandauthentication) but the response is a `org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized` (the username-password combination is correct)

couln't find any solution yet

here's the actual code

```
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter(this, BASE_URL);
    MobileUserRepository userRepo = restAdapter.createRepository(MobileUserRepository.class);
    String username = "test";
    String password = "1234";
    userRepo.loginUser(username, password, new MobileUserRepository.LoginCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AccessToken token, MobileUser currentUser) {
            Log.d("LoginActivity", token.getUserId() + ":" + currentUser.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Log.e("LoginActivity", "onError", t);
        }
    });
```

and the full stack trace

```
D/AsyncHttpClient: Headers were overwritten! (Accept | application/json) overwrites (Accept | application/json)
W/DefaultRequestDirector: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler: Progress 1335 from 1 (133500%)
W/remoting.RestAdapter: HTTP request (string) failed: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
E/LoginActivity: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
E/LoginActivity:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:404)
E/LoginActivity:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:161)
E/LoginActivity:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:178)
E/LoginActivity:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:109)
E/LoginActivity:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
E/LoginActivity:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/LoginActivity:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/LoginActivity:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/LoginActivity:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the e-mail address you used to register the user, instead of the user name.